# is atheism/agnosticism off-topic and subject to censorship?

Tags: discussion

The censorship that takes place at this site is absurd.  I can understand censoring bad language, personal remarks etc. - but ALL politely worded questions/comments should be allowed.  I personally find talk of "the lotus feet of the Lord" in 2017 off-putting, but just grin and bear it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69628/discussion-on-question-by-s-k-is-atheism-agnosticism-off-topic-and-subject-to-ce).