# why not give notification before adverse actions against questions/answers/comments?

Tags: feature-request

Its great to be god, but not so great to be victimized by god.

1. You put a comment out there, and one of the gods of the board feels it is inappropriate and summarily removes it without notification.
2. You put a question out there and sometimes it is summarily declared a duplicate by one of the gods.  It is then up to you to prove it is not.  at other times 5 people from a set of perhaps 10 decide your fate.
3. You put an answer out there and after three votes - poof! it is gone - no explanations given.

Why are posters being treated like schoolchildren?

Comment: For removing comments like that i already have a post [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/475/can-moderators-delete-comments-without-notifying-the-user-and-without-citing-val).. Now for answers i have seen that mods usually post a comment under the answer for the answer writer.. if they think that's needed i guess.. for 2 of my answers which were deleted in the past, they did like that..anyways if u find unfair deletion of questions or answers u can discuss here..

Answer (score 9):

Because... users behave like schoolchildren.

Lets get a few things up front here - I'm a mod *elsewhere* and I can't say I'm terribly active here. That said, this came up on MSE chat, and I'm primarily here cause, well, I don't think you're here for the right reasons.

Lets look at the help pages for a moment so that we're kinda on the same page

> Hinduism Stack Exchange is for followers of the Hindu religion and those interested in learning more about Hinduism.

Lets look at your [meta posts](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/12489/s-k).

I'm not entirely convinced questions like [this](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1024/is-atheism-agnosticism-off-topic-and-subject-to-censorship) reflect well, any of those points. Maybe following the atheism site, or finding some fora that reflects your views better. That said, none of your problems have anything to do with the site being about the faith, and more to do with a fundamental misunderstanding of the mechanism of the site

Lets put aside hinduism. I'm not exactly a religious scholar. Lets talk about *moderation*. I've been a moderator for 3 years, and nearly a 30k rep user on MSE, so I think I can assume I have a little knowledge of these fairly universal matters.

> (1) You put a comment out there, and one of the gods of the board feels it is inappropriate and summarily removes it without notification.

Well, comments are meant for *clarifications* not *commentary*. Once a comment's purpose is fulfilled, it's often deleted. Deletion of comments is something that's fairly common, yet misunderstood by many uses

> You put a question out there and sometimes it is summarily declared a duplicate by one of the gods. It is then up to you to prove it is not. at other times 5 people from a set of perhaps 10 decide your fate.

No gods or kings, Only men. Men (and women!) who's posted content that gives them sufficient trust by the system to give them the ability to close votes. Or a subset of them trusted by SE to moderate the site unilaterally. A power that we sometimes wish we could put aside. Amazingly, this is how it works elsewhere so, I don't think this has anything to do with gods, or mods incarnate

> You put an answer out there and after three votes - poof! it is gone - no explanations given.

You forgot the necessary downvotes. Or the flags. And well, sometimes we need to weed out the worst of the worst, or the merely terrible. The ones that are basically an argument in disguise.

Yanno? Mods arn't gods. Closer to herding dogs. Sometimes herding dogs herding cats. Nonetheless, if you're going to go "BUT MOOOOOM, TEACHER IS MEAN TO ME!" when your peers are working towards making this site a success... maybe you may need to relook your views, and spend a little more time thinking of how the SE model works, and less thinking how you're getting oppressed by the man.

Comment: *That last para though...* :-)

Comment: Its all self-indulgent self-justification.  it feels like terrorism when your content is removed without notification - and you haven't addressed that @journeyman geek  Its not only about me - it is about people using their petty powers to annoy users with heterodox views.

Comment: Is terrorism the new godwin? See, you're basically saying no one should have the authority to do, well, any of the things that we need to do to keep a site healthy. You *literally* need to contribute to the site to get the ability to close. As a beta site, mods are handpicked, and in my experience, they get a fair bit of mentorship from CMs and other mods as needed. If you're not happy with the moderation, try the contact us link.. Pretty much everything you complain about are fundamental ste mechanics, and I've generally addressed them as a long time user of the network.

Comment: lets try again.  a post about which day of week to get a haircut according to Hinduism got 10,000 views.  this makes my blood boil.  My posts infuriate a subset of users here - there is no doubt about it.  i wish we can all "just get along" - but given the utter lack of a sense of humor in many users that won't happen either.  All I am saying that heterodox posters are already up against it - don't add to their misery through arbitrary actions.  @journeyman geek

Comment: Oh, you certainly do annoy me already - *but* you're going to have better luck trying to reframe specific re-open requests with... less emotive language. Make a case for it - fit it within the context of the site, and clarify as needed. That said, attacking the "5 close voters" and referring to folks as "gods" in a mocking tone... just isn't cricket. Creating "us vs them" arguements about heterodoxy and orthodoxy doesn't help either. You're really going to have to work in the mechanics of the SE system

Comment: also... my mom kinda has a confusing, complex thing about days you're not supposed to do things, and ugh. I can totally see why such a question would be of interest to folks who kinda can't keep track of all the cultural baggage ;)

Comment: "Oh, you certainly do annoy me already" - work on that rather than making Olympian pronouncemnets

Comment: There's a lot fewer people who annoy me than not. I'm sure there's a good reason why.

Comment: that you go with the herd and the mavericks annoy you?